# Purchase posts in Rails structure

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have posts that users create and then other users can create them. There are some posts that have a specific quantity in stock and there are some that don't have a quantity [see what I am trying to achieve here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40690917/jquery-script-for-making-checkbox-appear-based-on-if-selected-category-contains). Based on those posts I need to be able to handle purchases of the stock as well as not take any stock if a post doesn't have a quantity and just keeps going.

What should my purchase model look include because right now I am just confused as to how to handle quantity management and posts that don't have a quantity all in the same model right now.

Comment: If you are handling purchases you are probably handling sales as well - i would think - and as such you need a header for purchases (and sales) and a related 'lines' model - the lines would be for each individual item - a purchase increases is a positive entry and a sales is a negative entry - and then you handle inventory by summing that column together...this of course is based on the minimal information you are giving

Comment: @MageeWorld I was thinking include the quantity in the Post model and including the quantity in the Purchase model then when a purchase occurs decrease the quantity of Post. Would that be the way to go?